# How to properly pass mysql connection to routes with express.js

Tags: node.js, express, node-mysql

I am trying to figure out the best way to pass a mysql connection (using node-mysql) between my routes for express.js. I am dynamically adding each route (using a for each file loop in routes), meaning I can't just pass in the connection to routes that need it. I either need to pass it to every route or none at all. I didn't like the idea of passing it to ones that dont need it so I created a dbConnection.js that the routes can individually import if they need. The problem is that I dont think I am doing it correctly. As of now, my dbConnection.js contains:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var db = null;
module.exports = function () {
    if(!db) {
            db = mysql.createConnection({
                socketPath: '/tmp/mysql.sock',
            user: '*********',
            password: '*********',
            database: '**********'
        });
    }
    return db;
};
```

And I am importing it into each route using:

```
var db = require('../dbConnection.js');
var connection = new db();
```

But I would like to do it like this:

```
var connection = require('../dbConnection.js');
```

When I try it like this, however, I get an error saying connection has no method 'query' when I try to make a query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Express - Passing mysql connection to scripts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844868/express-passing-mysql-connection-to-scripts)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I find it more reliable to use node-mysql's pool object.  Here's how I set mine up.  I use environment variable for database information.  Keeps it out of the repo.

### database.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
  user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
  password: process.env.MYSQL_PASS,
  database: process.env.MYSQL_DB,
  connectionLimit: 10,
  supportBigNumbers: true
});

// Get records from a city
exports.getRecords = function(city, callback) {
  var sql = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE city=?";
  // get a connection from the pool
  pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    if(err) { console.log(err); callback(true); return; }
    // make the query
    connection.query(sql, [city], function(err, results) {
      connection.release();
      if(err) { console.log(err); callback(true); return; }
      callback(false, results);
    });
  });
};
```

### Route

```
var db = require('../database');

exports.GET = function(req, res) {
  db.getRecords("San Francisco", function(err, results) {
    if(err) { res.send(500,"Server Error"); return;
    // Respond with results as JSON
    res.send(results);
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Could you elaborate on putting queries in a database folder? I'm relatively new to node and I'm finding it harder to do what I want asynchronously.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you not need to release the connection back to the pool in ````getRecords````? It seems like the ````connectionLimit```` would be hit after 10 requests?

Comment: You do actually, I missed it.  Will put that in there.  Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 1):

your solution will work if use db() instead of new db(), which returns an object and not the db connection

```
var db = require('../dbConnection.js');
//var connection = new db();
var connection = db();
```