# NodeJS / Express - Make Available MySQL Connection Object in Router File

Tags: node.js, express, node-mysql

I have the following in my `app.js` file:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3306,
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'mydatabase'
});
connection.connect();
```

In `routes/index.js`, I currently have only the boilerplate code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

module.exports = router;
```

How do I make available the `connection` object from the `app.js` file in `routes/index.js`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly pass mysql connection to routes with express.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800418/how-to-properly-pass-mysql-connection-to-routes-with-express-js)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I ended up splitting the database connection logic from the `app.js` file.  In a separate file called `connection.js`, I have the following:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3306,
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'mydatabase'
});

module.exports = connection;
```

Then in my route file, I add

```
var connection = require('../connection');
```

to the top of the file where all my other modules are brought in.  In my instance, the `connection.js` file is one level higher than my route file, hence the `../` in the `require()` function parameter.

Comment: That would be the other usual way. I like passing them in so I can easily mock them for testing.

Comment: @RobertMoskal 's answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/25125755/1489912) is better, because you can use it for connection pooling. This one will eventually leave you with no control over the connections created.

Comment: @LloydBanks in this example, is a new DB connection being instantiated in every file that has `var connection = require('../connection');`? So, does that mean, if we separate our routes into different files, we should close the connection after the route handlers are done using the connection?

Answer (score 11):

My preference is to do some simple dependency injection and pass the required resource into the router by wrapping the module in a function:

```
var express = require('express');

module.exports = function (connection) {
    var router = express.Router();
    //do stuff with the connection
    return router;

}
```

Then you just instantiate the router module in app.js as a function with the database connection as an argument:

```
app.use('/where/ever', require('./module-b')(connection));
```

Usually I wrap up the dependencies in an object:

```
app.use('/where/ever', require('./module-b')({db:connection}));
```

This way you don't have to keep changing the function signature as dependencies are added.  This gives you a super-lightweight inversion of  control container for your express applications.

Comment: How is the object being passed here?

Comment: As long as you wrap each module in a function, it's just a repetition of the same pattern.

Answer (score 0):

> Check out [express-myconnection](https://www.npmjs.org/package/express-myconnection), it lets you access the MySQL
>   connection from within your routes.

**Update:** After using express-myconnection in production, I would not recommend it - it leaks connections, causing requests to hang (callback will never be called), and it is no longer actively maintained.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and Lloyds' suggestion was kind of a solution for me but I just didn't want to be stuck on a single type of db, I want to be able to move my app to another db with just a new implementation of a single class.
So that worked for me:

```
function DataAccess(connectionData) {
    //Using the connectionData...
}

var _dataAccessInstance;

module.exports = function (connectionData) {
    if (!_dataAccessInstance) {
        _dataAccessInstance = new DataAccess(connectionData)
    }
    return _dataAccessInstance;
};
```

And then the usage will be just require the file:

```
//The object is the connection data to be sent to the module
var dataAccess = require('./data-access')({});
```

Sure, this has its own flaws like every module must know and send the connection data. But I assume the data is stored in the configuration and all hte modules can access it.