# Passing database connection around in a nodejs application

Tags: database, node.js

I'm using express 3 in my node application and I've broken my routes into separate files...

```
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
```

The problem is that I need a database connection in many of these routes. Should I be connecting to the database in each of the route files or can I connect in my main app file and somehow pass the connection to the includes?

---

I used express-generator to create a skeleton app.
In app.js the routes are included like this...

```
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
```

And in each other these files there are routes as follows...

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});
```

Comment: can you show how `routes` or `users` is defined?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly pass mysql connection to routes with express.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800418/how-to-properly-pass-mysql-connection-to-routes-with-express-js)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I simply keep the database connection in the app:

`app.set('db',new MyDAO(config));` <-- use where you define your routes.

then, inside the route, in `get()` or `post()` I simply do

`req.app.get('db').usercollection.find()`

This way you keep your database connection pool attached to the gloabl application context.

Alternative common approach is to extend `req` on every request, but it is executed every time:

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    req.db = db; //this db comes from app.js context where you define it
    next();
});
```

Comment: What is new `MyDAO(config)`?  If I was using monk and did `var db=require('monk')('localhost/dbname');` would that be the same?  I mean it works what I'm doing, just not sure if it's the same as you described.

Comment: Yes. Monk is kind of a universal Data Access Object (DAO) for Mongo. `MyDAO` here is simply an abstraction around backend to retrieve and store objects in readable and maintainable way. It typically has `getUserById()` or `getTodaysBlogEntries()` or `addChatMessage()` or similar, business-logic specific methods. If you change backend from MySQL to Mongo, you don't have to change the code in upper layers, you can just replace DAO. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object

Comment: great! save my day!

Answer (score 0):

The prevailing answer didn't work for me because I used the [typescript-express-starter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-express-starter) project which places the database functionality one level deeper into the project from the `controller` level to the `services` level. And short of using doing `service.call(req.app.get('db'), deleteParams)` to every service call there had to be another strategy.

Instead I just used a static `db.ts` file to declare and initialize the database value:

```
import { Knex } from 'knex';

const db: Knex = require('knex')({
  // debug only in development
  // this will cause knex to print extra helpful lines in the console
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
  client: 'pg',
  version: '13.2',
  connection: {
    host: process.env.RDS_HOSTNAME,
    user: process.env.RDS_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.RDS_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.RDS_DB_NAME,
  },
});

// perform a test query to verify the connection to the DB was successful
db.select('*')
  .from('auth_group')
  .then(rows => {
    console.log(rows);
  });

export default db;
```

And then in the service-level code I just imported it directly:

```
import db from '../db';
...
db.select()
...
```

Comment: I wonder this will connect to a new instance of db every time when imported to different files.